# Google Cloud Platform - Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am running a docker image of ArangoDB in a VM, with the following environment variable set:
ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD.  The instance runs fine, but I needed to change the root password, so I edited the VM and restarted, but the newly defined password is not working.  It still refers to the old password.  My boot disk is set to be "kept" when the instance is deleted.  Could that be the source of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your VM and find the external IP. Visit that IP in your browser on port number 8529.
Example: <-vm-external-ip-address->:<8529>
Enter root as the username and provide the current root password.
Select _system DB.
Select users on the left side panel.
click on root.
Click on change password.
Enter a new password and save.

Enabling "keep disk" does not create any issue to change root password.

Refer to the link [arangodb-image-on-gce](https://medium.com/@gaforres/running-a-standalone-arangodb-on-google-compute-engine-using-docker-a8cbb183fd3) for more information.